# How to use metaio mobile SDK to draw sth. rather than directly load geometric data from files

Tags: iphone, sdk, augmented-reality

Currently, I'm working on one AR software development on iphone and android platform. And I'm new to Metaio SDK... I really don't know how to draw something with OpenGL or somethings else alike. All that I can find out is to load one file(like 'md2') into source code and then SDK itself will handle all the others. However, for me, I just want to display one rectangle on the base of tracked marker's coordinate and put some textures on it. Is there someone who can help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [tutorial for Android](http://docs.metaio.com/bin/view/Main/CustomRendererExample) that shows how to use the SDK with an external OpenGL renderer.

For iPhone, the example is missing but the integration will be very similar to the Android.